# How to aggregate, obtain percentage, and reassign column and row with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three columns Decision as A (accepted) and D (denied), and year and month

```
Decision   Year   Month
A   2003   1
A   2005   3
D   2005   2
D   2003   3
A   2004   1
```

I want to restructure it based on counts of decision='A', then make a new df with Year being the index and each month as a column. Note: each cell now becomes the no. of 'A' in that Year and Month

```
Year Month1 Month2 Month3 ...    
2002   1   3   4
2003   2   4   5
2004   2   3   5
2005   5   3   42
2006   4   2   12
```

Similarly I want another df for Decision='D'

```
Year Month1 Month2 Month3 ...    
2002   4   4   3
2003   2   4   23
2004   4   1   12
2005   4   2   31
2006   4   2   22
```

But ultimately, I want each cell to be the percentage of (no. 'A')/(no. 'A' + no. 'D')

```
Year Month1 Month2 Month3 ...    
2002   .2   .43   .57
2003  (etc)
2004  (etc)
2005   (etc)
2006   (etc)
```

I have tried groupby with pandas without success, I think I can create different lists to obtain the counts then merge the lists together to create a df, but I wonder if Pandas has something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value_counts` within `groupby` using `normalize=True`

```
d1 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).Decision.value_counts(normalize=True)
d1.xs('A', level='Decision').unstack('Month', fill_value=0).add_prefix('Month')

Month    Month1    Month2    Month3
Year                               
2002   0.200000  0.428571  0.571429
2003   0.400000  0.666667  0.416667
2004   0.285714  0.300000  0.312500
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Decision=['A'] * 29 + ['D'] * 46,
        Year=[2002] * 8 + [2003] * 11 + [2004] * 10
           + [2002] * 11 + [2003] * 12 + [2004] * 23,
        Month=[
            1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
            1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,
            3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    ))[['Decision', 'Year', 'Month']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the end results without building the 2 intermediate DFs.

```
#use groupby, count As and get percentage, finally pivot month to columns.
df.groupby(by=['Year','Month'])['Decision'].apply(lambda x: len(x[x=='A'])/float(len(x))).reset_index(level=1).pivot(columns='Month').fillna(0)
Out[257]: 
      Decision          
Month        1    2    3
Year                    
2003       1.0  0.0  0.0
2004       1.0  0.0  0.0
2005       0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Do you have nulls in Year or Month columns? Maybe try df.fillna(0).groupby... to see if you still get the error?

Comment: I checked, don't have any missing values in Year or Month